# Image and sound in Array change by clicking on next button in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, audio

EDIT- I found the solution for the issue 
I put mysound++;  View.OnClickListener aButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener(

I have app with array of pictures and sounds. When user click next button the pictures change to next one. The problem I have is that I can't change the sound to the next one as well. The app is playing the first sound all the time or it plays all sounds from array.
I need to have the sound changes to next one after next button is clicked to reflect picture change. Example: picture a1 = sound1, picture a2 = sound2.

private ImageButton MainImage, ImageLeft, ImageRight;
    private ImageButton nextButton;

```
private int currentImage = 0;
int[] images = { R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.b1, R.drawable.c1, R.drawable.d1, R.drawable.e1, R.drawable.f1 };
private int currentImage2 = 0;
int[] images2 = { R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.b2, R.drawable.c2, R.drawable.d2, R.drawable.e2, R.drawable.f2 };
private int currentImage3 = 0;
int[] images3 = { R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.b3, R.drawable.c3, R.drawable.d3, R.drawable.e3, R.drawable.f3 };
private int[] sounds = { R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3, R.raw.sound4, R.raw.sound5, R.raw.sound6,  };
private int mysound = 0;
private int[] sounds2 = { R.raw.sound1a, R.raw.sound2a, R.raw.sound3a,R.raw.sound4a, R.raw.sound5a, R.raw.sound6a,  };
private int mysound2 = 0;
MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aplhascreen);

    MainImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImageLeft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ImageRight = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

    ImageLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphascreen.this, sounds[0]);
            mp.start();
            mysound++;

            ImageRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphascreen.this, sounds2[0]);
                    mp.start();
                    mysound2++;

                }

            });

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(aButtonChangeImageListener);

        }

        View.OnClickListener aButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentImage++;
                currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
                currentImage2++;
                currentImage2 = currentImage2 % images.length;
                currentImage3++;
                currentImage3 = currentImage3 % images.length;
               mysound++;
                mysound = mysound % sounds.length;
               mysound2++;
               mysound2 = mysound2 % sounds2.length;

                MainImage.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
                ImageLeft.setImageResource(images2[currentImage2]);
                ImageRight.setImageResource(images3[currentImage3]);

            }
        };
    });
}}
```

Comment: You have to pass mySound counter in sound array. You have pass 0.It will play only one sound for all.

Comment: I was trying   mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphascreen.this, sounds[mysound]); but than all sounds from array can be played on button click instead only one as needed. Tried also    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphascreen.this, sounds[mysound % sounds.length]); but with no positive results

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, need to reset `MediaPlayer` before assigning new track

```
ImageRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.reset(); // new line
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphascreen.this, sounds2[0]);
                mp.start();
                mysound2++;

            }

        });
```